# Make the icon of new button added in a matplotlib figure larger

Tags: python, button, matplotlib, icons

I added some buttons to a matplotlib figure but the icon seems so small in the button.

[image]

Is there a way to render them larger? I would like to see the icon as big as the button box.

Example of code I use to add the button (in pyqt environment):

```
self.figure = plt.figure() 
self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.figure)

self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar(self.canvas, self)

self.load_scale = QPushButton()
self.load_scale.setIcon(QIcon(os.path.join('icons','Resize-icon.png')))
self.load_scale.setToolTip("rescale plot") 
self.toolbar.addWidget(self.load_scale)

self.load_scale.clicked.connect(self.rescale) 

layout = QVBoxLayout()
layout.addWidget(self.toolbar)
layout.addWidget(self.canvas)
self.setLayout(layout)
self.canvas.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution.
After having set the icon, we just need to remove the border and to resize the icon.
We can do so with:

```
self.load_scale.setStyleSheet('QPushButton{border: 0px solid;}')
self.load_scale.setIconSize(QSize(25, 25))
```

That gives me a better looking icons:
[image]